Ubuntu 24.04 custom themes
I started with a new Ubuntu 24.04.1 install on a Dell Latitude 7400. When trying to install a custom theme following this https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-mac-os-mojave-theme-ubuntu-19-10/ the theme was not working with several applications such as Nautilus, Firefox. When trying to go back to the default Awadita applications the window border became transparent and the window management buttons were hardly visible. I found one piece of information on the net saying that with moving to gtk4 themes are no longer supported. Is this true? If not, how do I install a custom gtk4 theme and have it available with all applications?

First, install the dependencies
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin git

Download the theme with
git clone https://github.com/vinceliuice/Mojave-gtk-theme

Now, open the theme directory in terminal
cd Mojave-gtk-theme

Now, install it with libadwaita support
./install.sh --libadwaita


does this work with Wayland or do I have to boot into X11?

AFAIK It should work in Wayland

I followed your advice. When I run the install script I get two error messages for each theme:
./install.sh: line 162: glib-compile-resources: command not found
./install.sh: line 179: glib-compile-resources: command not found

here https://github.com/vinceliuice/Mojave-gtk-theme/issues/143 I found that you have to install libglib2.0-dev-bin first. Then the themes get installed without error.

After installing Mohave-light using Tweaks, the theme is present but there are still applications which don't show it (Firefox, App-center) most apps seem to work though.

You will have to connect snap apps separately https://github.com/vinceliuice/Mojave-gtk-theme?tab=readme-ov-file#on-snapcraft. You can alternatively install firefox with apt https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

@Ewald If my answer works for you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark in the left side
